# MySQL: why undo log is required in the processes of database recovery?

Tags: mysql, transaction-log, transaction, recovery

Let's imagine that an incident happens when you updates.

```
start transaction;
update users set gender = 1 where id = 3;
```

1. Undo log space is allocated.
2. Previous values are copied to undo log
3. Record of undo log modifications are written to redo log.
4. page is modified in buffer pull.
5. Record of page modification are written to redo log, and this page is marked as dirty.
6. then, an incident happen, MySQL crashes!

we restart MySQL, then recover from an incident, there are three steps:

1. Analysis
2. Redo, which will restore the state when MySQL crashed.
3. Undo.

For step3, we are undo uncommitted transactions through undo log in backwards order.

My questions are:

1. Can we do step3 by undo `redo log` that caused by uncommitted transaction, rather than apply `undo log`?
2. Why `undo log` is required in the step3?
3. Is undo log for `recover from an crash that happens within recovery`?

Comment: Have you read [The basics of the InnoDB undo logging and history system](https://blog.jcole.us/2014/04/16/the-basics-of-the-innodb-undo-logging-and-history-system/)

Comment: MySQL is designed to "roll back" but not "roll forward".

Comment: @danblack I think this article is to explain the relationship between `MVCC` and `Undo` log. I have no doubt that undo is very import in MVCC. But when it comes to recovery, I can't figure out why undo log is necessary.

Comment: I have now crashed DB that has lost an Undo log and cannot recover from that. Shame no one answered your question